# Run-Time Error 3075 with CurrentDB.OpenRecordSet

Tags: ms-access, syntax-error

I am very new to VBA and keep running into this error. I am trying to set up a appointment system that allows me to book in clients, without double booking.

Run-Time Error ‘3075’:
Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression ‘Appointment Date’.

```
Private Sub AvailableTime_Enter()
    
    Dim i As Date, n As Integer, oRS As DAO.Recordset
    Dim sSQL As String, dDuration As Date
    Dim dLowerbreak As Date, dUpperBreak As Date

    AvailableTime.RowSourceType = “Value List”: Available Time.RowSource = “”
    If IsNull(Start) Then Exit Sub Else i = Start
    If me.NewRecord = True Then
       DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
    End If
    sSQL = “SELECT PhysioID, Appointment Date, Available Time”
    sSQL = sSQL & “ FROM qryTreatments”
    sSQL = sSQL & “ WHERE PhysioID=“ & Me.PhysioID & _
                “ AND Appointment Date=#” & me.AppointmentDate & “#”
    **Set oRS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sSQL)**
    dDuration = TimeValue(“00:30”)
    dLowerbreak = Break - TimeValue (“00:25”) ‘Break is a field
    dUpperBreak = Break + TimeValue (“00:25”)
    
    If oRS.RecordCount = 0 Then
      Do
        If i <= dLowerbreak Or i >= dUpperBreak Then 
            AvailableTime.AddItem i 
        End If
        I = i + dDuration 
     Loop Until i >= txtEnd
    Else
      Do
        If i <= dLowerbreak Or i >= dUpperBreak Then
          oRS.FindFirst “[Available Time] Between #” & i - TimeValue(“00:00:05”) & _
                            “# And #” & i + TimeValue(“00:00:05”) & “#”
          If oRS.NoMatch Then AvailableTime.AddItem i
        End IF
        I = i + dDuration
     Loop Until i >= txtEnd
  End If
  oRS.Close
End Sub
```

The bit in bold ** is the thing it highlights when I press debug.

Comment: As you have a space in the field name, you need to wrap it in square brackets - `[Appointment Date]`.

Comment: @Applecore Thank you! I shall have a play and try and get it to work - thank you!

Comment: @Applecore Any chance you know why it is now saying “No appointments” when there are plentiful of time slots?

Comment: Nowhere do I see "No appointments" in code. Is the RecordCount not 0? Are your date values in Access standard structure (mm/dd/yyyy)?

Comment: @June7 Ah yes, I have it in a different place, I have a different code saying if there is no time available then it will pop up with no appointments, though it is always doing it now. I will try with adjustments :D

Answer (score 0):

Try with these adjustments:

```vb
Private Sub AvailableTime_Enter()
    
    Dim i As Date, n As Integer, oRS As DAO.Recordset
    Dim sSQL As String, dDuration As Date
    Dim dLowerbreak As Date, dUpperBreak As Date

    AvailableTime.RowSourceType = "Value List": Available Time.RowSource = ""
    If IsNull(Start) Then Exit Sub Else i = Me!Start

    If Me.NewRecord = True Then
       DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
    End If
    sSQL = "SELECT PhysioID, [Appointment Date], [Available Time]"
    sSQL = sSQL & " FROM qryTreatments"
    sSQL = sSQL & " WHERE PhysioID=" & Me.PhysioID & "" & _
            " AND [Appointment Date]=#" & Format(Me!AppointmentDate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#"
    Set oRS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sSQL)

    dDuration = TimeSerial(0, 30, 0)
    dLowerbreak = DateAdd("n", -25, Me!Break)
    dUpperBreak = DateAdd("n", 25, Me!Break)
    
    If oRS.RecordCount = 0 Then
        Do
            If i <= dLowerbreak Or i >= dUpperBreak Then 
                AvailableTime.AddItem i 
            End If
            i = i + dDuration 
        Loop Until i >= Me!txtEnd
    Else
        Do
            If i <= dLowerbreak Or i >= dUpperBreak Then
                oRS.FindFirst "[Available Time] Between #" & Format(DateAdd("s", -5, i), "hh:nn:ss") & "#" & _
                    " And #" & Format(DateAdd("s", 5, i), "hh:nn:ss") & "#"
                If oRS.NoMatch Then AvailableTime.AddItem i
            End IF
            i = i + dDuration
        Loop Until i >= txtEnd
    End If
    oRS.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for the adjustments. It is still doing the same thing. With highlighting the Set oRS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sSQL).
It might just be that I haven’t properly set up my database for something like this - I am 100% new to Access and coding. Thank you though :D